# Adicionar Filtro Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Galera estou querendo adicionar um filtro no wordpress na area de postagem :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E queria que aparecesse apenas postagens que essa função fosse aplicada :

```
function ag_display_custom_meta_box( $post ) {

wp_nonce_field( 'ag_featured_custom_box', 'ag_featured_custom_box_nonce' );

$stored = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ag_featured_post', true );

$options = array(
    '0' => 'Não usar matéria como destaque',
    'principal' => 'Grande',
    'secundaria' => 'Pequenos',
    'slider' => 'Slider',
    'colunaaposentados' => 'Coluna Aposentados',
    'colunaunidades' => 'Coluna Unidades',
    'colunaeventos' => 'Coluna Eventos',
    'colunaesportes' => 'Coluna Esportes',
    'colunanoticias' => 'Coluna Noticias',
    'colunafenae' => 'Coluna Fenae'
);

$output = "<select name='ag_featured_post_position'>";

foreach ($options as $value => $title):

    $output .= "<option ";

    if(esc_attr($stored) == $value)
        $output .= "selected='selected' ";

    $output .= "value='{$value}'>{$title}</option>";

endforeach;

$output .= "</select>";

echo $output;

}

/**
* @param $post_id
*/
function ag_save_meta_box( $post_id ) {

// Validations
$nonce = $_POST['ag_featured_custom_box_nonce'];

if(!isset($_POST['ag_featured_post_position']) || !wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'ag_featured_custom_box'))
    return $post_id;

if(defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
    return $post_id;

// Check the user's permissions
if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
} else {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
}

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_ag_featured_post', sanitize_text_field( 
$_POST['ag_featured_post_position']));
}

add_action('save_post', 'ag_save_meta_box');
```

Eu li algo sobre *add_filter* , mas eu não sei onde aplicar e onde colocar exatamente...

A utilização exata desse filtro é : no meu site tem uma area de 'destaque' que utilizo essa função para escolher o que vai e o que não vai lá... o problema que tenho inúmeras postagens diarias e não são todas que vão para o destaque, e o pessoal responsável pelas postagens gostaria de filtar apenas as que estão no destaques...  e não sei como fazer isso.

Como é em wordpress o doc que eu li comentou em ser no arquivo function.php

Comment: A função `ag_display_custom_meta_box` retorna que tipo de valor? ou não tme retorno

Comment: Na verdade, não tem bem um retorno, mas ela mostra as postagens selecionada. Que querendo ou não é um retorno ... posso estar falando merda hahaha

Comment: Da para colocar a função toda? Pois geralmente as funções do wordpress, quando usadas como filtros, costumam retornar alguma coisa.

Comment: Adicionei o resto da função.

Answer (score 0):

A função que você busca é a [add_screen_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_screen_option)

para adicionar a opção você pode fazer

```
function add_screen_option(){
    $option = 'per_page';

    $args = array(
        'label' => 'Movies',
        'default' => 10,
        'option' => 'cmi_movies_per_page'
    );

    add_screen_option( $option, $args );
}
```

dentro do init por exemplo.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_screen_option' );
```

consulte [este tutorial](https://chrismarslender.com/2012/01/26/wordpress-screen-options-tutorial/) para ainda mais detalhes